# Accordion inside other accordion does not resize height of body content with Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I have done with Bootstrap 2.0 an accordion which has other accordion in its body:

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordion1" >
    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a href="#content1" data-toggle="collapse"
                data-parent="#accordion1" class="accordion-toggle">Accordion1</a>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-body" id="content1" >
            <div class="accordion-inner">
                <div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
                    <div class="accordion-group">
                        <div class="accordion-heading">
                            <a href="#content2" data-toggle="collapse"
                                data-parent="#accordion2">Accordion2</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="accordion-body collapse" id="content2">
                            <div class="row-fluid">
                                <div class="span3">
                                    <a href="#">Button1</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="span3">
                                    <a href="#">Button2</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="span3">
                                    <a href="#">Button3</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Using Internet Explorer 9, the first time that I load the principal accordion (`accordion1`), which is loaded opened and the `accordion2` closed, when I open the `accordion2` ,it resizes the height of the `accordion1` to show its content correctly.
But after that, if I collapse `accordion2`, and after I collapse `accordion1` too, when I re-open `accordion1` and after `accordion2`, `accordion2` doesn't resize the height of `accordion1`...and therefore I don't see the content of `accordion2`.

With Firefox there are no problem, Firefox resizes the content of `accordion1` without any problem. 
I tried to put property `height:auto` but it doesn't do anything...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem.
The solution is that Internet Explorer 9 have this bug, but in Internet Explorer 10 this problem is solved.